# Bypass recaptcha to webcrawl a site

Tags: python, get, request, web-crawler, recaptcha

I am currently trying to webcrawl the following website https://eu.tamrieltradecentre.com/ in order to be able to retrieve the list of items sold in the MMO and their prices. However, their list appears to be safe-guarded by a recaptcha.

Edit: Solved using selenium!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show the code that you have used so far in a code segment (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details).

Comment: Look into using PIL and PyTesseract to solve captchas.